# ¿cómo puedo verificar si el número es palíndromo sin utilizar listas ni string en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Necesito saber que librerías o fórmulas puedo utilizar para poder obtener un número palíndromo.

tengo algunas limitantes para poder realizarlos:

- no puedo utilizar listas
- no puedo utilizar strings.

¿existe alguna forma?, quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Pedir recomendaciones no es muy bien recibido aquí, mejor comparte lo que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte

Comment: Creo que también sería bueno elaboraras un poco más que es lo que necesitas. Porque si necesitas cualquier palindromo de n+1 dígitos, solo es hacer (10^n)+ 1

Comment: Lo digo porque en la descripción dices obtener un palindromo, pero en la pregunta pones verificar

Comment: @JhonRM, solo nos dieron las indicaciones de verificar si un numero ingresado por el teclado es palíndromo, pero no puedo utilizar ni strings ni listas.

Comment: @christian no busco que me realicen el ejercicio, sino ideas de como poder desarrollarlo. Desarrollarlo utilizando listas o strings es muy fácil. Pero me piden realizarlo sin estos.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Voltea los dígitos de un numero
def voltear(_n):
    n = _n
    rev = 0
    while(n > 0):
        a = n % 10
        rev = rev * 10 + a
        n = n // 10

    return(rev)

while(1):
    numero = int(input('Ingrese un numero '))

     if numero%10 == 0: numero = numero//10

    if numero == voltear(numero) :
        print('ES palindromo')
    else :
        print('NO es palindromo')
```

Answer (score 1):

A lo mejor esto te sirve. Soy **muy novato en Python**, pero vamos a probar:

```
mivar = input("Dime numero: ")
test= True
j=0  

for i in reversed(range(len(mivar))):
    if mivar[i] != mivar[j]:
        #son distintos, así que test pasa a falso y salimos
        test=False
        break
    else:
        j +=1
    #si i o j son 0, hemos llegado a la mitad de la palabra, así que rompemos bucle
    if j==0 or (i+1)==0:
        break

print(test)
```

Mediante bucle y con dos variables posicionables, compruebas el primero con el último, el segundo con el penúltimo, así hasta cruzar la mitad de la cifra. Por defecto, asumimos que el número es palíndromo, e iniciamos test como TRUE, pero si en algún momento en la comparación no se cumple, pasamos test a FALSE (no es palíndromo) y salimos del bucle.

Aquí el código en ejecución con varios números:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]